# Escape Blade templating limited to text with VueJs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im facing something strange.

I have something like this :

`<span class="label label-@{{type}}" v-on:mouseover="changeType">@{{type}}</span>`

With `data: { type: 'primary' }` for exemple.

However, the output of this once treated by Laravel is

`<span class="label label-{{type}}">primary</span>`

Why is the first {{type}} not recognise and why is it not change?

Is there a way to fix that?

### Edit:

So it was due to the depreciation of interpolation inside attribute.

The solution is to use something like `:class="type"`.

However how do you add something before type? Since I want `label- + "type"`

Comment: it seems like you are not binding to the element download the vue dev tools plugin that should help you. el: 'body' or reference an id

Comment: +1 for the vue dev tools plugin however it was not that at all it is due to the depreciation of interpolation inside attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind it with a simple `:class` element:

```
<span class="label" :class="'label-' + type">primary</span>
```